# Javascript how to return number with x decimal places

Tags: javascript

For a given integer I want to return a number with that many decimal places. For example `const decimals = 5` should return `.00001`. I tried this `10 ** (-1 * decimals)` but instead of `.00001` I am getting `.00000999999999999999`. What is going on here? What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You're doing it the correct way, the result you're getting is because floating point can't represent that value exactly.

Comment: Use `toFixed()` to specify how many decimal places to round to.

Comment: I get your desired result in FF, and your shown in chrome. Looks like a small error in the exponentiation approximation, which probably doesn't count as a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```js
const decimals = 5;
const res = (1 / 10**decimals).toFixed(decimals);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: this is NOT a good answer.  The answer below is much better

Comment: @DCR Although the second answer is good and is recommended in other questions, I presented this solution as OP is already trying to do it without any function but was facing the issue of the resulting value.

Comment: I'm interested in knowing why you didn't like the answer.

Comment: it doesn't really work.  Try it for 6 7 8 or 9 decimal places

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`.toFixed(nN)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

```js
const decimals = 5;

let num = .0123456789;

console.log(num.toFixed(decimals));
```